# Missing configuration drop down buttons in Graphical Layout editor

Tags: android, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

I have two xml layouts in my project in Eclipse and when i want to edit them in the graphical layout tab, only one of them has the configuration drop-down buttons in the section above the layout. I would post up pictures but I don't have high enough reputation yet. 
It contains buttons to choose the type of phone/tablet you want to display on, the screen orientation, the Theme, associate activity etc.

I want both of them to have it but I'm not sure how to put it back. Does anyone know how to make it appear?

Thanks in advance